# Is there really no way to use hyphens and text-transform at the same time?

Tags: css, css-hyphens

```css
p {
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px dashed #555;

  -ms-hyphens: auto;
  -moz-hyphens: auto;
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto;
 }
 .uppercase {
  text-transform: uppercase;
 }
```

```html
<p lang="en">A conversation about sustainable carsharing.</p>
<p lang="en" class="uppercase">A conversation about sustainable carsharing.</p>
```

If I use CSS: `text-transform: uppercase` to convert everything to capital letters, the automatic hyphenation `hyphens: auto` no longer works – in Chrome (121.0..) on MacOs (14.2)

Any ideas to solve this problem?
Thank you!

Here is a screenshot to illustrate this:
[image: Screenshot, Chrome on MacOs]

Comment: Your snippet works for me in FireFox

Comment: It works for me in Safari on Mac

Comment: I see the probem on Edge/Chrome (Windows 10). No problem on Firefox. What browser/OS are you using?

Comment: The problem is with Google Chrome 121.0 and MacOs 14.2.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `{hyphen:auto}` property, you can use:

```
overflow-wrap: break-word;
```

or

```
word-break:break-word;
```

I think it should work.

Comment: The wrap works, but the dash is missing.